# PIL can not deal with images generated by uvccapture

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, debian, python-imaging-library

I use `uvccapture` to take pictures and want to process them with the help of `python` and the `python imaging library (PIL)`.
The problem is that `PIL` can not open those images. It throws following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 6, in <module>
    im = Image.open(infile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

My python code looks like this:

```
import Image

infile = "snap.jpg"
im = Image.open(infile)
```

I tried to save the images in different formats before processing them. But this does not help. Also changing file permissions and owners does not help.
The only thing that helps is to open the images, for example with `jpegoptim`, and overwriting the old image with the optimized one. After this process, `PIL` can deal with these images.

What is the problem here? Are the files generated by `uvccapture` corrupt?

**//EDIT:** I also found out, that it is not possible to open the images, generated with `uvccapture`, with `scipy`. Running the command

```
im = scipy.misc.imread("snap.jpg")
```

produces the same error.

```
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only found a workaround to this problem. I processed the captured pic with [jpegoptim](http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/jpegoptim) and afterwords PIL could deal with the optimized image.